# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined,, trying to read from mongodb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, get-request

/// I am following a turorial from youtube,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nUbNn0voiBI&t=88s
and faced an error,

Proxy error: Could not proxy request /notes from localhost:3000 to https://localhost:3001/.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (EPROTO).

````
function Notes(){
    const [notes, setNotes] = useState([{
        name: '',
        email: '',
        phone: '',
        message: ''
    }])

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("/notes").then(res => {
            if(res.ok) {
                return res.json()
            }
        }).then(jsonRes => setNotes(jsonRes));
    })

    return <div className="container">
        <h1>Notes page</h1>
        {notes.map(note => 
            <div>
                <h1>{note.name}</h1>
                <p>{note.email}</p>
                <p>{note.phone}</p>
                <p>{note.message}</p>
            </div>            
            )}
    </div>
}

export default Notes;```
````

Comment: Might be the response you are getting from API call is not array or might be undefined. Because, .map will run only on array. Can you check what response are you getting from API?

Answer (score 0):

you should try to console.log(jsonRes) and make sure you are returning an array. The map function only works on arrays :/ also the useState for notes is fairly pointless, just make it useState([]). if you console.log(jsonRes) returns a list of objects. You can use
setNotes(jsonRes).toArray() and that should work. it all depends what you're returning from mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You can check if notes are undefined before using map, i will use your code to do a example below.

```
function Notes(){
    const [notes, setNotes] = useState([{
        name: '',
        email: '',
        phone: '',
        message: ''
    }])

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("/notes").then(res => {
            if(res.ok) {
                return res.json()
            }
        }).then(jsonRes => setNotes(jsonRes));
    })

    return <div className="container">
        <h1>Notes page</h1>
        {notes !== undefined && notes.map(note => 
            <div>
                <h1>{note.name}</h1>
                <p>{note.email}</p>
                <p>{note.phone}</p>
                <p>{note.message}</p>
            </div>            
            )}
    </div>
}

export default Notes;
```

That way you prevent your array been undefined resulting this error you describe.